# LaTeX Table Positioning

Tags: floats, positioning

This is similar, but not the same, as a previous question.

I want to do the following things:

- Number tables and figures separately
- Put tables exactly where I want them

To do the first one, I just use 'figure' and 'table' environments in the appropriate place. But the table environment doesn't seem work when I use `\begin{table}{H}`, which stops me being able to do the second thing. Any suggestions?

Correction: I should have said `\begin{table}[H]`

Comment: You need to include the [float package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and use [H] not {H}.

Comment: Please link this to the previous question.

Comment: `H` is not a standard placement specifier. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @TomasLycken The question you linked to doesn't seem at all related to this, so I doubt that was what he was referring to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Werner noted in a comment, you should have square brackets (`[]`) rather than curly braces (`{}`) around the placement specifier. Also, as doncherry noted in another comment,`H` isn't a  standard placement specifier.

Try `\begin{table}[hp]` instead, or if that doesn't work, try `\begin{table}[!hp]` (note the exclamation mark).

If you still do not achieve exactly what you want, then `\usepackage{float}` and try `\begin{table}[H]` as Werner suggested.

Comment: yeah, `\usepackage{float}` does the trick too.

Comment: No. As Herbert provides, he shouldn't use a floating environment at all.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Not using a floating environment at all does more than just changing the way LaTeX positions the table. Since the question explicitly talked about the `table` floating envirionment, I assumed they were a requirement.

Comment: @TomasLycken `[h]` or even `[!h]` shouldn't really be used as they almost inevitably take floats to the end of the document, almost always it is better to use `[htp]` or `[!htp]` see recent comments in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46046/how-to-float-figure-close-to-its-description-in-the-text#comment95515_46046

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Noted, thanks! I chose to edit only to `[hp]`, mainly because the `t` can induce behavior that is hard to troubleshoot (for example if you want the table after an orphaned line at the top of the page, LaTeX is likely to place the table above...). Now, `h` should be used whenever possible, and if there is no room a float page will be produced (if for no other purpose, to indicate that there isn't enough room for the table in the intended place).

Answer (score 10):

Since you don't want your tables to float, don't use a float environment like `figure` but simulate it:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}%% only for demo

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{some noinsense text.}
\begin{tabular}{l}
Zeile 1\\
Zeile 2\\
Zeile 3\\
Zeile 4
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, so `\captionof{table}{some noinsense text.}` does all the TOC stuff if I don't put it any kind of float! Excellent.